# Why `*(block **)p` is not the same as `block` if `p` is of type `block*`? [CPython source code]

Tags: python, c, low-level

I am trying to read some of the CPython source code, specifically `obmalloc.c` (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/obmalloc.c). When I am reading how the equivalent of malloc and free work I come up with these lines:

```
pymalloc_free(void *ctx, void *p){
...
*(block **)p = lastfree = pool->freeblock;
pool->freeblock = (block *)p;
...
}
```

and

```
pymalloc_alloc(void *ctx, void **ptr_p, size_t nbytes){

bp = pool->freeblock;
if ((pool->freeblock = *(block **)bp) != NULL) {
...
}
...
}
```

Here block is `typedef uint8_t block;` and the `pool` struct is:

```
struct pool {
...
block *freeblock;
...
}
```

I cannot make sense of all the code that uses `*(block **)p`. My questions are:

1. How these assignments are working?
2. I thought that `*(block **)p` is supposed to be idempotent if `p` is of type `block*`, why is not in this case.
3. This seems to be used to implement a linked list, how that mechanism works and how it relates to `*(block **)p`?

Comment: You're thinking of `*&p`.

Comment: The extra `*` at the beginning is confusing me, but if the block did not have it `(block **)p` It looks like its casting p to be a pointer to a pointer that points to a `uint8_t`. But I'm not sure what the extra `*` at the beginning is doing. I’m curious to see the answer myself

Comment: `pool->freeblock = (block *)p` same as `pool->freeblock = (uint8_t *)p`So `pool->freeblock` must except pointers of type `uint8_t` Possibly  why he might be casting `p`  to that type. But I'm still confused about the `*` at the bigging. note "Link p to the start of the pool's freeblock list.  Since
      the pool had at least the p block outstanding, the pool
      wasn't empty "

Answer (score 2):

The code is

```
pymalloc_free(void *ctx, void *p){
    ...
    *(block **)p = lastfree = pool->freeblock;
    pool->freeblock = (block *)p;
    ...
}
```

First of all, `block` is a typedef for `uint8_t` i.e. a 8-bit byte. It is used just as a semantic marker here, to say that the pointer points to a memory block to allocate instead of any random bytes somewhere or a character string.

You asked:

> 2. I thought that `*(block **)p` is supposed to be idempotent if `p` is of type `block*`, why is not in this case.

It isn't, it would convert `block *` to `block **` and then dereference the pointer. Note that in this case the pointer given is a `void *`, not `block *`.

> 1. How these assignments are working?

The memory pointed to by `p` is accessed as if it pointed *to* a `block *`. Instead of the casts. If there were an intermediate variable because it would make it more obvious what is happening:

```
block **bpp = p
*bpp = lastfree = pool->freeblock;
```

and

```
bp = pool->freeblock;
block **bpp = bp;
if ((pool->freeblock = *bpp) != NULL) {
}
```

> 3. This seems to be used to implement a linked list, how that mechanism works and how it relates to *(block **)p?

The free memory blocks are all just chunks of bytes of particular size. The first `sizeof (block *)` (i.e. `sizeof (uint8_t *)`)  bytes of a free block point to the next block of bytes, hence the pointer to the beginning can be cast to a pointer to a pointer and dereferenced to get *this* pointer value located in the first bytes.

Note that the block must also start at an address that is divisible by `_Alignof (block *)`, which the `pymalloc` carefully maintains.